# Deleting multiple slices from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a given numpy array and a list containing a number of slice objects (alternatively containing `(start, end)` tuples). I am looking to remove the slice object positions from the original array and get a second array with the remaining values.

Toy example:

```
myarray = np.arange(20)

array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])

mylist=(slice(2,4),slice(15,19))
```

Do something and result should be

```
array([0, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14])
```

The array can be in a few hundred thousand large, the list of slice objects can contain a few thousand elements and I need to run the operation often, so speed is somewhat important.

Numpy delete does not take a list of slices as far I can see?

For now I am generating the complement of my slice object list and slicing that, but generating the complement is a somewhat awkward process where I am sorting my slice list then iterating through it, creating the complement slice objects as needed. I am hoping there is a more elegant way I have not figured!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set()` to identify which positions will be kept and `np.take()` to obtain the corresponding values, doing something like:

```
ind = np.indices(myarray.shape)[0]
rm = np.hstack([ind[i] for i in mylist])

ans = np.take(myarray, sorted(set(ind)-set(rm)))
```

Note that `np.hstack()` is used to obtain a single array with all the indices that will be removed. This takes about half the time of @HYRY's solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.r_[]` to join the slices into an array:

```
myarray = np.arange(20)
mylist=(slice(2, 4),slice(15, 19))
np.delete(myarray, np.r_[tuple(mylist)])
```

output:

```
array([ 0,  1,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19])
```

But I think it's not very fast.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way to join the slices cleanly; however, I think using the composite is the way to go. Perhaps try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

# Create test data
n_data = 1000000
n_slices = 10000

data = np.arange(n_data)
slices = []
for i in range(n_slices):
    r = np.random.randint(n_data-1000)
    slices.append(slice(r,r + np.random.randint(1000)))

# Remove slices
keep_mask = np.ones_like(data, dtype=bool)
for slice in slices: keep_mask[slice] = False
data = data[keep_mask] # or np.take, etc.
```